# Youtube iFrame Api for live videos?

Tags: youtube, embed, live-streaming, youtube-iframe-api

I'm trying to implement live video from youtube channel with youtube iframe api. There is a videoId property in api and it works for live videos too but we have to add video id every stream start.

There is a solution in iframe live video `https://www.youtube.com/embed/live_stream?channel=CHANNEL_ID`. How can i use it in iframe api?

Comment: Have you been able to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

I came across this same issue. I figured out that you can directly add the iframe with the src instead of an empty div. Then give it an id and pass that to the new YT.Player instance.

ex: 
html:
`<iframe id="player" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/live_stream?channel=CHANNEL_ID?enablejsapi=1"></iframe>`

js: 
`var player = new YT.Player('player', {});`

Comment: I get "Uncaught ReferenceError: YT is not defined"

Comment: @Roberto Becerra You need to add `<script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>`