# embedding multiple Youtube livestream and manage display with buttons

Tags: javascript, html, youtube, embed, display

I am trying to setup a website page where 2 permanent live streams (from 2 different channels) are embedded. 2 buttons are present on the page, allowing the user to  display 1 video or the other.

However I can't manage to make this work. I am now trying with regular youtube embed, but only one is displaying, the buttons don't have any effect. Also the autoplay doesn't seem to work...

I already tried the Livestream part, this works well, but not with 2 livestreams.
Any advice where to look into. Thank you !

```js
function showcam(num) {
  for (let i = 1; i < 2; i++) {
    document.getElementById("camera" + i).style.display = 'none';
  }
  document.getElementById("camera" + num).style.display = '';
  console.log(num)
}
```

```css
iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: none;
  max-width: 100%;
  z-index: -5;
}
```

```html
<div id="cameramenu">

  <ul>
    <button id=button1 onclick="showcam(1)">
             <li> camera 1 </li>
           </button>
    <br>
    <button id=button1 onclick="showcam(2)">
             <li> camera 2 </li>
           </button>
</div>

<div id=cameravideo>
  <div id=camera1>
    <iframe id=camera1 title="Live-stream of the machine" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/hgZqTIOzOp4?autoplay=1&modestbranding=1&color=red&showinfo=1" playsinline>
           </iframe>
  </div>

  <div id=camera2>
    <iframe id=camera2 title="Live-stream of the crowd" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/CA5-UT_6Cxs?autoplay=1&modestbranding=1&color=red&showinfo=1" playsinline>
           </iframe>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: You are repeating the same ids on the div and nested iframes.  Ids are expected to be unique.  Possibly your issue.

Comment: not the issue, I tried with the id on the iframe or on a div wrapper and it's not working in either cases :/ thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the iframe api in order to be able to control the video. From there, you'll be able to add more than 1 video and do make your own play buttons or toggle between them. If you need further help, I can try and give you an example that toggles between 2 videos.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

https://jsfiddle.net/842u0f6v/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <!-- 1. The <iframe> (and video player) will replace this <div> tag. -->
    <div id="player"></div>

    <script>
      // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
      var tag = document.createElement('script');

      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

      // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
      //    after the API code downloads.
      var player;
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '390',
          width: '640',
          videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
      }

      // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
      function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.playVideo();
      }

      // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
      //    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
      //    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
      var done = false;
      function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
          setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
          done = true;
        }
      }
      function stopVideo() {
        player.stopVideo();
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you ! I managed to get both videos working ! I think I need to use the Youtube Livestream API to get the the video embeded to be live-streams, am i right ?

Comment: As far as I know, their Livestream API doesn't do anything with embeds. The iframe API I linked above works with livestreams too. You just need to give it the video ID. If you need some further help, I can try and throw together a little working example of what you're trying to do. Are you trying to have both livestreams play at the same time? Or just be able to toggle each one on and off with a button?

Comment: That would be great ! I would like to be able to toggle between each of them with buttons. I figured out the part with buttons but when I can't figure out where to put the channel ID (permanent link). It didnt work when I replaced the videoId by my channel ID (videoId: 'live_stream?channel=my channel id)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47241553/youtube-iframe-api-for-live-videos I think this is related actually and might help to embed the livestream (permanent url )

Comment: Yea the iframe_api doesn't allow you  to set the iframe to the channel ID live page. Just last week I was trying to do that and went through the source with no luck. That link you posted is correct. You have to set the iframe with the channel hard link first. Then after it loads and fetches the video, you can load the iframe_api and control it. Sorry I didn't mention that before, I thought you were just using the video ID.

Comment: Here's the URL's for the live channel embed and the chat. You cant set the live chat using a channel ID. You have to use a video ID. You can grab that ID using the iframe_api after the stream has loaded. `https://www.youtube.com/embed/live_stream?channel=<channel-id>` `https://www.youtube.com/live_chat?v=<video-id>&embed_domain=<pages.domain-here.com>&dark_theme=1`

Comment: thank you for your help ! forgot to answer but this has been really helpful !